# How to call a view based on a condition using a db query

Tags: laravel

I have 6 views, I want to call a view based on a condition, in my case I'm loading contracts, each contract is within a specific view

- contract_1.blade.php
- contract_2.blade.php
- ...
- contract_6.blade.php

How can I call the view contract_1.blade.php when contract_1 is selected? to explain this more, I have Contract class:

```php
namespace App;

use \DateTimeInterface;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class Contract extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    use HasFactory;

    public const TYPE_LOCATION_SELECT = [
        'contract_1' => 'Contrat de bail meublée',
        'contract_2' => 'Contrat de bail vide',
        'contract_3' => 'Contrat de bail commercial',
        'contract_4' => 'Contrat de bail saisonnier',
        'contract_5' => 'Contrat de bail professionnel',
        'contract_6' => 'Contrat de bail d\'habitation',
    ];

    public $table = 'contracts';

    protected $appends = [
        'attachment',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'start_rent_date',
        'end_rent_date',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'user',
        'type_location',
        'full_name',
        'dob',
        'identity',
        'address',
        'estate_type_id',
        'estate_location',
        'rent_period',
        'start_rent_date',
        'end_rent_date',
        'equipments',
        'superficie',
        'etage',
        'porte',
        'charges',
        'garantie',
        'total_amount',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')->fit('crop', 50, 50);
        $this->addMediaConversion('preview')->fit('crop', 120, 120);
    }

    public function estate_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Estate::class, 'estate_type_id');
    }

    public function getStartRentDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;
    }

    public function setStartRentDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['start_rent_date'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
    }

    public function getEndRentDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;
    }

    public function setEndRentDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['end_rent_date'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
    }

    public function getAttachmentAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getMedia('attachment');
    }

    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

My generated pdf file is called getpdf.blade.php

```html
{{$contract_type = \App\Contract::where(['location_type' => $contract->location_type])}}
@if ($contract_type == contract_1)
@extends('layouts.contract_1')
@else
extends('layouts.contract_2')
@endif

@section('content')
<div class="content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {{ trans('global.show') }} {{ trans('cruds.contract.title') }}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ route('admin.contracts.index') }}">
                                {{ trans('global.back_to_list') }}
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ route('admin.contracts.getpdf', $contract->id) }}">
                                {{ trans('global.datatables.pdf') }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.id') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->id }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.user') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->user }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.type_location') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ App\Contract::TYPE_LOCATION_SELECT[$contract->type_location] ?? '' }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.full_name') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->full_name }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.dob') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->dob }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.identity') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->identity }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.address') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->address }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.estate_type') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->estate_type->estate_type ?? '' }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.estate_location') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->estate_location }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.rent_period') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->rent_period }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.start_rent_date') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->start_rent_date }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.end_rent_date') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->end_rent_date }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.equipments') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->equipments }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.superficie') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->superficie }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.etage') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->etage }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.porte') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->porte }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.charges') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->charges }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.garantie') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $contract->garantie }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        {{ trans('cruds.contract.fields.attachment') }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach($contract->attachment as $key => $media)
                                            <a href="{{ $media->getUrl() }}" target="_blank">
                                                {{ trans('global.view_file') }}
                                            </a>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ route('admin.contracts.index') }}">
                                {{ trans('global.back_to_list') }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image]

I'm getting this error:

> ErrorException
> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/app/resources/views/admin/contracts/getpdf.blade.php)

I'm not sure where the mistake is.

Comment: `contract_1` -> `"contract_1"` in your blade `if` statement

Comment: You may want to also consider doing this logic in the controller, and control which view gets rendered from there. Just to be more inline with MVC conventions, but it is optional

Comment: i agree with you, i just don't know how to implement it correctly, unless if you can help and learn from you.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your error is on the first line, you are literall doing `{{ $variable = object }}` but that `object` is not stringable, so it does not know how to turn the object to a string.

So, this:

```php
{{$contract_type = \App\Contract::where(['location_type' => $contract->location_type])}}
```

should be:

```php
@php
$contract = \App\Contract::where(['location_type' => $contract->location_type])->first();
@endphp
```

And then, the `if`:

```html
@if ($contract_type == contract_1)
```

should be:

```html
@if ($contract->type_location == "contract_1")
```

Have in mind that `->first()` could return no object (`null`), so doing `$contract->type_location` could throw an error. In that case, I would recommend to check how to solve those types of issues depending what PHP version you have.

Comment: thank you i got this error Use of undefined constant contract_1 - assumed 'contract_1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View:

Comment: My bad, we wrote `contract_1` instead of `"contract_1`", I will edit the answer

Comment: thank you, I guess it's working however I'm getting in error : `ErrorException
Undefined index: (View: /var/www/neom/vouchermanager/resources/views/layouts/contract_1.blade.php)`  line 53:  `    return $num[17][$number];` I don't know why this line throw this error as it was working just fine

Comment: While you read my previous comment, I created another contract with "contract_2" however it's always calling contract_1.blade.php. my contract_2.blade.php is an empty file so it should call an empty document instead of calling contract_1.blade.php, maybe I'm missing something from the code: 
`@php
$contract = \App\Contract::where(['type_location' => $contract->type_location])->first();
@endphp
@if ($contract->type_location == "contract_1")
@extends('layouts.contract_1')
@elseif ($contract->type_location == "contract_2")
@extends('layouts.contract_2')
@endif
`

Comment: @ZackTim I would mark this answer as correct and create a new question, as you now have a new error that is not related to the question and would need more data

Comment: Yes but it's not selecting the correct view, it should not call contract_1.blade.php, it should call contract_2.blade.php and display a blank page

Comment: Then your issue is in the controller, you are looking for `$contract->location_type`, so you already have the contract hardcoded to be that on the view... I am telling you, that is a new error, create a new question

Comment: I removed the function code from the view, it's always loading only contract_1.blade.php

Comment: @ZackTim yes, as I told you before, the controller is already passing a `$contract` (I didn't see that), so your error is in there. Again, this answer solved your main issue, you know have a new one that is not related to the question, so please do mark this answer as correct and create a new question with the new issues (and share the controller code). I will not answer this topic anymore

Comment: I'm sorry I lost you here, so what is your current answer for this specific question? why are you pushing  me to create a new question for the same issue over again?

Comment: It is not a new question about the same issue, you originaly had a PHP Fatal Error, now you have another issue, that is you cannot get the desired view to be displayed

Comment: Consider I don't have a PHP Fatal Error, I removed the whole function because what it does it simply converting digits to letters, the ouput of 0 will be zero. So basically it's not my main issue, the main issue is, when I implemented the correcting code you suggested, it will still call contract_1.blade.php when it should call contract_2.blade.php so the question is, can you revise your answer? maybe the condition is wrong?

Comment: I have found the solution myself:
``@php
 {{$contract = \App\Contract::where(['type_location' => $contract->type_location])->first();}}
 $contract->type_location;
@endphp

@extends('layouts.'.$contract->type_location)``